# Selecting second occurence of word using regex

Tags: regex

I have this string output:

```
"Appliances Air Conditioners
Appliances Split AC"
```

I am trying to use regex to remove the second occurrence of "Appliances" word:

```
(Appliances.\*?(Appliances))*
```

But getting no success.

Comment: What regex tool are you using and what's your expected output?

Comment: *regex* isn't a programming language. You need to get more specific about in which way you are using the regex especially which programming language you are using.

Comment: I am using regex101 for now, i want to select second occurence of "Appliances" and then later on remove it from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for:

```
\b(Appliances\b[\s\S]*?)\bAppliances\s+
```

And replace by `\1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sD4lF4/1)

You need to use `DOTALL` or `[\s\S]` to match a newline.